# iOS class design

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I have a class with about 50 methods which I have split up into a number of categories.

Since all the methods are in categories, my original class is now empty.

Is this a bad design? How else can I split up the large class?

Comment: what are the sections you have split the code up into? maybe subclasses would be a better approach

Comment: You should supply details of the class and what the categories represent for us to provide meaningful counsel. This is a bit too abstract.

Answer (score 0):

If you can group your methods in a bunch of logical functionality. Categories can be good option because it helps you manage your code. But if you have not logically connected methods there isn't good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whether that is bad design is a pretty much a subjective topic. It depends on a number of factors. Without more details about your class, it's hard to tell; maybe your design is already a "good" one. But let me propose a different approach, maybe that one helps you determine whether your current design is the right one for you:

The reason why you've put all those methods (which you can logically divide into categories) into one class is most likely because they need access to the same data, which you have stored in your instance variables. If not, you already can easily split the class up.

If all those methods need access to the same data, a different approach would be to create a kind of "context" object, with getter and setters for the necessary data. You could then create classes containing the methods that you have in your categories and assign each one the same context.

You might need to have some of these classes immediately react to changes in the context class. One solution might be Key-Value Observing.

But beware: having 10 different classes/objects that you need to access all the time might be worse than having one big class.